# Why are all my files in sever being read during a process while i did not write any command to do so

Tags: php

I am running a nohup process to get twitter output using tmhOAuth.php.

When I ran strace in command line for this process, it shows that all the files in my server are being opened and read like this

---

```
getpeername(7, 0x7fff010336c0, [112])   = -1 ENOTCONN (Transport
endpoint is not connected) stat("/var/www/html/jigale2/cacert.pem",
{st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=251894, ...}) = 0
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {10329, 530757562}) = 0
open("/var/www/html/jigale2/cacert.pem", O_RDONLY) = 8 fstat(8,
{st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=251894, ...}) = 0 read(8, "##\n##
 Bundle of CA Root Certific"..., 251894) = 251894    close(8)             
 = 0 stat("/var/www/html/jigale2", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|S_ISGID|0775, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0 openat(AT_FDCWD, "/var/www/html/jigale2",
 O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|O_CLOEXEC) = 8 getdents(8, /* 44
 entries */, 32768)    = 1664 stat("/var/www/html/jigale2/jigale2.sql",
 {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=9418690, ...}) = 0
 clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {10329, 534636974}) = 0
 open("/var/www/html/jigale2/jigale2.sql", O_RDONLY) = 9 fstat(9,
 {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=9418690, ...}) = 0 read(9, "--
 phpMyAdmin SQL Dump\n-- versio"..., 9418690) = 9418690 close(9)       
 = 0 stat("/var/www/html/jigale2/all_stars_post_json.php", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=498, ...}) = 0
 clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {10329, 542772563}) = 0
 open("/var/www/html/jigale2/all_stars_post_json.php", O_RDONLY) = 9
 fstat(9, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=498, ...}) = 0 read(9,
 "<?php\r\ninclude(\"db_connection.ph"..., 498) = 498 close(9)         
 = 0 stat("/var/www/html/jigale2/README.md", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=3242, ...}) = 0 clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, {10329,
 543108179}) = 0 open("/var/www/html/jigale2/README.md", O_RDONLY) = 9
 fstat(9, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0664, st_size=3242, ...}) = 0 read(9, "#
 jScroll - jQuery Plugin for In"..., 3242) = 3242 close(9)
```

---

I posted only a few lines of the strace output. Actually all my files on the sever are being read, while I did not write any command to behave like this.

nohup command:
nohup php ./twitter_autofill_jigale.php &

Here is the code I am using to get twitter feed.

```
<?php
include("db_connection.php");
require 'tmhOAuth.php';

$connection = new tmhOAuth(array(
    'consumer_key' => '****',
    'consumer_secret' => '***',
    'user_token' => '****', //access token
    'user_secret' => '****' //access token secret
));

//class to show exception messages
class customException extends Exception 
{
    public function errorMessage() 
    {
        //error message
        $errorMsg = 'Error on line '.$this->getLine().' in '.$this->getFile()
        .': <b>'.$this->getMessage().'</b> nohup is stopping here';
        return $errorMsg;
    }
}

//try for catching nohup error
try 
{
    while(true)
    {
        $sql_twt = 'SELECT id, twitter_pageID FROM celebrities WHERE twitter_pageID !="0"';
        $result_twt = $conn->query($sql_twt); 

        while($row_twt = $result_twt->fetch_assoc())
        {
            $twt_pageID = $row_twt['twitter_pageID'];
            $twt_celeb_id = $row_twt['id'];

            //getting the latest post id for the current celeb from twt_latest_post table
            $latest_twt = "SELECT post_id FROM twt_latest_post WHERE twitter_pageID ='$twt_pageID' ORDER BY post_id DESC LIMIT 1";
            $obj_twt = mysqli_fetch_object(mysqli_query($conn,$latest_twt));

            if ($obj_twt)
            {
                $latest_twt_id = $obj_twt->post_id;
                $parameters = array();
                $parameters['count'] = '25';
                $parameters['user_id'] = $twt_pageID;
                $parameters['since_id'] = $latest_twt_id;
                $parameters['include_rts'] = 'false';
                $twitter_path = '1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json';
            }
            else
            {
                $parameters = array();
                $parameters['count'] = '25';
                $parameters['user_id'] = $twt_pageID;
                $parameters['include_rts'] = 'false';
                $twitter_path = '1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json';
            }

            $http_code = $connection->request('GET', $connection->url($twitter_path), $parameters );

            if ($http_code === 200) 
            { 
                $response = strip_tags($connection->response['response']);
                $twt_data = json_decode($response, TRUE);

                for ($i = 0; $i <count($twt_data); $i++)
                {
                    $created_time =  strtotime($twt_data[$i]["created_at"]);
                    if (array_key_exists('text', $twt_data[$i]))
                    {
                        $message = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $twt_data[$i]["text"]);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $message = "";
                    }
                    if (array_key_exists('media', $twt_data[$i]["entities"]))
                    {
                        $full_picture = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $twt_data[$i]["entities"]["media"][0]["media_url"]);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $full_picture = "";
                    }
                    $platforms_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $twt_data[$i]["id_str"]);

                    //inserting twitter feed
                    $sql_twt_feed= "INSERT INTO feed (celeb_id, created_time, message, full_picture, platforms_id, platform) VALUES ('$twt_celeb_id', '$created_time', '$message', '$full_picture', '$platforms_id', 'Twitter')";

                    //loading post ids into twt_latest_post table
                    $sql_twt_latest_post = "INSERT INTO twt_latest_post (twitter_pageID, post_id) VALUES ('$twt_pageID', '$platforms_id')";

                    if (!$conn->query($sql_twt_feed) || !$conn->query($sql_twt_latest_post)) 
                    {
                        //echo "Error details: " . mysqli_error($conn) . "<br>";
                        //throw exception if nohup stops for some reason
                        $error = mysqli_error($conn);
                        throw new customException($error);
                    } 
                }
                sleep(10);
            }

        }
    }
}

//catching the nohup error
catch (customException $e) 
{
  //display custom message
  echo $e->errorMessage();
}
?>
```

db_connection.php has the connection variables to my database.

Here's the link to tmhOAuth.php https://github.com/themattharris/tmhOAuth

I am using while condition to continuously get twitter feed.

I don't know how to use strace properly or read the output. There is another facebook process, and strace output for that process does not show any files being opened and read.

What is causing the twitter process to behave like this? Or is this a hacking attempt to read all my php files on server?

Please suggest any ways to solve this problem.

Thank you, 
Gautami

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you be more specific on what commands/scripts you are executing?

Comment: Hello Jan Greve, I have added the code and command that's being used. Thank you for your response.

Comment: I can't even figure out how the complete file count of a typical Linux server. How have you determined it's reading *all the files on the server* and not just the files required to serve an HTTP request?

Comment: Hi  Álvaro González. I am sorry for miscommunication. What i meant was that all my project files are being read. The root of the website is in /var/www/html. All the files in this directory are being read.